How to delete CMake generated files after blocking an in-source build?
In my CMake project, I'm using the code below to detect in-source builds:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.29)
project( NoInSource )

function( NoInSourceBuilds )
  if ( ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} STREQUAL ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} )
    execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E rm CMakeCache.txt)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "In-source builds are not allowed!")
  endif()
endfunction()

NoInSourceBuilds()
message( "Won't get here")


(Base on code from: Preventing in-source builds)
To create the in-source build, I type:
cmake -B . -S .

It correctly detects the in-source build.
But, the code above fails to delete the CMakeCache.txt file :(
Is there a way to remove the generated files prior to exiting?
Whatever the solution, I do not want to use any undocumented variables.

Detect it before project() ?

@KamilCuk Placing the call before project() has no effect. Feel free to try it yourself to confirm. I'm using cmake version 3.29.
